# md5 doesn't work when decrypting and validating login details

Tags: php, mysql, md5

I have encrypted and store password. Once user login I want to decrypt and validate .But following code is not able to do that. Can any body help with this?

```
<?php
   include("config.php");


   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword =md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']));


      $sql = "SELECT id FROM services WHERE user_name = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);



      if($count == 1) {

         echo "success";

      }else {
         echo "fail";
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: "I have encrypted and store password." – No, you haven't. You have hashed the password. MD5 is not an encryption algorithm, it is a hashing algorithm. One that was broken over a decade ago, I might add. "Once user login I want to decrypt and validate ." – You can't. Since you didn't encrypt the password, you cannot decrypt it either.

Comment: You'll want [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) rather than md5 - but even then you **should not** be able to retrieve a password from your database, nobody should. By using a salted hash (which you should) you're storing something more like a fingerprint of the password, rather than the password itself.

Comment: You also might want to use prepared statements instead of putting variables straight into a SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It isn't necessary to escape value, that will be md5-hashed. You even could change the password (and md5 hash) if it contains some special char. For example, lets see at password's `test'` hashes:

   ```
   echo md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']));
   echo md5($_POST['password']);
   ```

Output is:

```
e1e7975d4f1958297ede35ea4fc13a27
5c28a8c6d799d302f3ef53afefdfc81b
```

2. You shouldn't do:

   ```
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   ```

because you don't use it later and you don't check if num_rows > 0 and it'll give an error if there are 0 records.

Answer (score 0):

md5 should never ever be used for storing passwords.

First off it's been known to be broken for decades already, but that's not the worst of it in this case.

Secondly you're using it without a random salt, which makes it vulnerable to rainbow table attacks.

Finally, and most crucially, it's a fast algorithm, and hence completely unsuitable for password hashing. Any hacker worth their "salt" that gets a hold of your user's hashed passwords will make short work of finding >90% of the passwords in a matter of hours as your users will use predictable passwords instead of truly random ones.

You really need to use something like password_hash().

Answer (score -1):

**I found other method and this was success.Thank for your help**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
 //Username and Password sent from Form
 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
 $password = md5($password);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM services WHERE user_name='$username' AND '$password'";
 $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 $res=mysqli_num_rows($query);

 //If result match $username and $password Table row must be 1 row
 if($res == 1)
 {
 //header("Location: welcome.php");
   echo "did";
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Invalid Username or Password";
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM services WHERE user_name='$username' AND '$password'";` ... that's not actually validating the password, you could put in any old junk for the password and, as long as the username was correct, you'd be logged in.

Comment: You should also add `LIMIT 1` to the query and change the if to strict comparison `if ($res === 1)`.